# Assertion failure in +[NSJSONSerialization ensureObjectForKey:inDictionary:hasExpectedType:nullAllowed:]

Tags: box-api

I'm using box-ios-sdk-v2 (v1.1.0) and when I call:

```
[[BoxCocoaSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager folderInfoWithID:BoxAPIFolderIDRoot
                                          requestBuilder:nil
                                                 success:folderSuccess
                                                 failure:failure];
```

I get an assertion failure:

```
*** Assertion failure in +[NSJSONSerialization ensureObjectForKey:inDictionary:hasExpectedType:nullAllowed:], ~/MyApp/Pods/box-ios-sdk-v2/BoxSDK/Categories/NSJSONSerialization+BoxAdditions.m:27
An uncaught exception was raised
+[NSJSONSerialization(BoxAdditions) ensureObjectForKey:inDictionary:hasExpectedType:nullAllowed:]: Unexpected JSON null when extracting key modified_at from dictionary {
    "content_created_at" = "<null>";
    "content_modified_at" = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "<null>";
    "created_by" =     {
        id = "";
        login = "";
        name = "";
        type = user;
    };
    description = "";
    etag = "<null>";
    "folder_upload_email" = "<null>";
    id = 0;
    "item_collection" =     {
        entries =         (
                        {
                etag = 0;
                id = 1092326452;
                name = CSS;
                "sequence_id" = 0;
                type = folder;
            },
                        {
                etag = 1;
                id = 680411078;
                name = New;
                "sequence_id" = 1;
                type = folder;
            },
                        {
                etag = 2;
                id = 8224096128;
                name = ".apdisk";
                "sequence_id" = 2;
                sha1 = e8389b6e4307a798b0811cabc94144ce381b3312;
                type = file;
            }
        );
        limit = 100;
        offset = 0;
        order =         (
                        {
                by = type;
                direction = ASC;
            },
                        {
                by = name;
                direction = ASC;
            }
        );
        "total_count" = 3;
    };
    "item_status" = active;
    "modified_at" = "<null>";
    "modified_by" =     {
        id = 181198661;
        login = "grigutis@iu.edu";
        name = "John Grigutis";
        type = user;
    };
    name = "All Files";
    "owned_by" =     {
        id = 181198661;
        login = "grigutis@iu.edu";
        name = "John Grigutis";
        type = user;
    };
    parent = "<null>";
    "path_collection" =     {
        entries =         (
        );
        "total_count" = 0;
    };
    "purged_at" = "<null>";
    "sequence_id" = "<null>";
    "shared_link" = "<null>";
    size = 289;
    "trashed_at" = "<null>";
    type = folder;
}
```

Is this a problem with my account (modified_at really shouldn't be null) or the SDK? If it's my account, how would I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the Box iOS SDK. Thanks for the bug report! Root folders are special folders on Box. Root folders are "virtual folders" that don't actually exist (this explains why they always have an id of 0 across all user accounts). Because root folders (and trash folders) are virtual folders, we don't track some metadata for them, like the modified_at timestamps.

The list of fields that may be null for root/trash folders:

- sequence_id
- etag
- created_at
- modified_at
- trashed_at
- purged_at
- content_created_at
- content_modified_at
- shared_link
- parent

I've put together a patch that will suppress these Nulls and convert them to nil. (I didn't want to turn all of the accessors to id return type just for the special case of the root/trash folders.) https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2/pull/47

Once this commit is merged, we'll cut a bugfix release.

We should document this sort of edge case/special case behavior. I'll let our documentation team know.

Comment: Fixed in v1.1.1. Thanks again! https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2/releases/tag/v1.1.1

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I see you updated the podspec too. You're the man!